# Toggle show/hide html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a script/flow. I'd like to use jQuery to swap html elements (12 total divs) and stay in one, centered and responsive section element. The first div is visible and the rest hidden. In each div, and not in a static button list, there would be links that let you hide the current div, and unhide another div based on its id.

JQuery Toggle seems to be the most easy, but I'm not figuring out how to toggle more than 2 elements. I'm open to any solutions, however.

```
<section>
<div id="a">
    <p>content here</p>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#" id="b-link">b</a> <a href="#" id="c-link">c</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="b">
    <p>content here</p>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#" id="a-link">a</a> <a href="#" id="c-link">c</a> 
<a href="#" id="d-link">d</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="c">
    <p>content here</p>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#" id="a-link">a</a> <a href="#" id="b-link">b</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="d">
    <p>content here</p>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#" id="a-link">c</a> <a href="#" id="b-link">a</a>
        </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. cannot have multiple `#link` elements. Ids mus be unique in the dom. 2. Where is your attempted script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as you have requested, I've made a few changes to the code.

The buttons have a custom attribute `for` which corresponds to the `id` of the panel which they display. This then toggles the class `.active` which shows the panel via `CSS`. Panels are by default hidden until they are 'active'.

The jquery is pretty straight forward, attaching a click event to any button with the class `.panel-switch`. It is fully commented below. My preference is to use CSS but instead of adding a class you could simply `.toggle()` the DOM elements using the same selection method.

Let me know if this wasn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to the buttons with class panel-switch
$(".panel-switch").click(function() {

  // Hide current active panel
  $(".panel.active").removeClass("active");

  // Activate chosen panel
  $(".panel#" + $(this).attr("for")).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}

.panel.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="panel active" id="a">
    <p>Panel A</p>
    <div class="links">
      <button class="panel-switch" for="b">b</button> <button class="panel-switch" for="c">c</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" id="b">
    <p>Panel B</p>
    <div class="links">
      <button class="panel-switch" for="a">a</button> <button class="panel-switch" for="d">d</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" id="c">
    <p>Panel C</p>
    <div class="links">
      <button class="panel-switch" for="a">a</button> <button class="panel-switch" for="b">b</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" id="d">
    <p>Panel D</p>
    <div class="links">
      <button class="panel-switch" for="c">c</button> <button class="panel-switch" for="a">a</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is beautiful. I was about to resort to SwapDivsWithClick for all 25+ scenarios, but this is much more efficient.

Comment: No problem, glad it's helped!